# MySQL query with multiple left joins and different WHERE clauses for each

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

I'm modifying a query that previously left joined two tables, but now needs  to add a third, and I'm struggling with some of the conditions being applied.

**This is the original query:**

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(act.rowId) q4Act 
        FROM accounts a 
        LEFT JOIN leads l ON a.accountId = l.accountId 
        LEFT JOIN activities act ON act.leadId = l.leadId AND act.classification = 'Positive' AND activityDate >= '2016-10-31' AND activityDate < '2017-02-01' 
        WHERE a.accountId = '$id' 
        GROUP BY a.accountName ";
```

This worked fine, ensuring that the only results from the activities table were meeting the three AND conditions and the `accountId` was the one being queried.

However, I split two tables and wanted to update this query. My first attempt was this next query, where I added the new left join, removed a condition from the first one and added it to the second one. This, however, returns totally different results.

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(act.rowId) q4Act 
        FROM accounts a 
        LEFT JOIN leads l ON a.accountId = l.accountId 
        LEFT JOIN activities act ON act.leadId = l.leadId AND activityDate >= '2016-10-31' AND activityDate < '2017-02-01' 
        LEFT JOIN interestingMoments im ON im.rowId = act.imId AND im.classification = 'Positive' 
        WHERE a.accountId = '$id' 
        GROUP BY a.accountName ";
```

My next attempt was to move the condition on the new table below the joins like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(act.rowId) q4Act 
        FROM accounts a 
        LEFT JOIN leads l ON a.accountId = l.accountId 
        LEFT JOIN activities act ON act.leadId = l.leadId AND activityDate >= '2016-10-31' AND activityDate < '2017-02-01' 
        LEFT JOIN interestingMoments im ON im.rowId = act.imId 
        WHERE a.accountId = '$id' 
        AND im.classification = 'Positive' 
        GROUP BY a.accountName ";
```

The above returns the same results when there's a positive count, though it doesn't return `a 0 count` like the first query did. This isn't a big deal, but I'd like to see if this is the proper way to construct this query.

Is this the best way, or should I be going about it a different way?

Comment: IS im.classification =  act.classification ? if yes why you dont add this in on condition?

Comment: @Mahesh I wasn't clear on this, act.classification no longer exists, that's the part of the activities table that was split out and put into a separate interestingMoments table

Comment: @sorak you mean specify it as the ON field? act.activityDate is unique to the activities table, I'm afraid -- the only common field is leadId

Comment: I was just saying I use table aliases everywhere even when the field name is unique, as it makes things more obvious and eliminates possible surprises. I deleted it after re-reading the queries and deciding it really wouldn't matter. *shrug*

Comment: Hi. You are not clear. Please xplain what was "split" exactly how into what. Also give relevant constraints. Apparently from your comments it was activities into at least activities & interestingMoments. You need to know how to reconstruct activities. You could then just replace it by a subquery in the first query. Although there might be an unnested equivalent. Please clarify by editing your post, not comments. Please read & act on [mcve]. PS Read some definitions & examples of inner & outer join. Outer join returns inner join rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by nulls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placing the constraint on the JOIN versus in the WHERE clause really creates no difference. If the tables is huge, it may affect time to run the SELECT, but that difference is likely small and can still probably be mitigated by indexes.

Comment: If that's the case, shouldn't all three queries basically return the same results? But the 2nd query has different results.

Comment: Query #2 will return activities that do not have any associated interesting moments.

Query #3 has the im.classification constraint in the WHERE clause, so the record of an interesting moment is required to exist for anything to be returned.

Comment: Query #3 returns the right numbers, but it returns nothing if there's no interesting moments, whereas Query #1 would still return something because it finds the account. Q3 doesn't even find the account at that point, so is there a better way to structure the query, or should I leave well enough alone?

Comment: The idea behind a LEFT JOIN is that it still returns values on the left even if the table that you're joining (which goes on the right of the result set) returns nothing. Moving the constraint into the WHERE clause makes it a rule for returning a record at all, vs just LEFT JOINing extra data. What do you mean it returns the right numbers?

Comment: Q1 returns the proper counts of interesting moments, whereas Q2 doesn't. Q3 returns the proper counts as well, the only difference being that if the count of interesting moments = 0, it returns nothing at all (vs Q1 returning a count of 0). I'm guessing this could be a case where I'm using the wrong JOIN type?

Comment: Q2 is LEFT JOINing interesting_moments, so that property does not constrain records returned. You'll have accounts with leads and activities in your set that do not have associated interesting_moments. The way to make that return what you expect is either to move the constraint outside the WHERE as in Q3, or use regular JOIN operations instead of LEFT JOIN. This is because you aren't counting interesting_moments, but accounts. You need to reduce the set to only accounts with interesting_moments.